# Relation between the number of generators of ideal and class number

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have a small problem on the number of generators of  ideal and class number.

Let $F$ be a number field with class number $h_F$. If $h_F=1$ then  every ideal of $F$ is princile ideal.
Assume $h_F>1$. Can we say that the number of generators of ideals of $F$ is at most $h_F$? If it is true, where can I find a proof?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that the number of generators of ideas of $F$ is at most $2$! Rings of integers in number fields are "Dedekind domains", and Dedekind domains have this property. Knowing the words "Dedekind domain" should allow you to search for all kinds of relevant information; [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597543/in-a-dedekind-domain-every-ideal-is-either-principal-or-generated-by-two-element) is relevant, for example.