# Find all prime ideals of $\mathbb{F}_3[x,y]/(y^2−x^3+x)$ whose intersection with $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is equal to $(x^2+x+2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Find all prime ideals of $\mathbb{F}_3[x,y]/(y^2−x^3+x)$ whose intersection with $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is equal to $(x^2+x+2)$.

I'm a completely beginner in commutative algebra and try to learn it in advance. I have actually no idea about how to solve this question.

My thought till now:

1. The prime ideals of $D:=\mathbb{F}_3[x,y]/(y^2−x^3+x)$ are the canonical images of the prime ideals containing $(X^2+Y^2−1)$.
2. $(y^2-x^3+x)$ and $(x^2+x+2)$ are both irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3[x,y]$; $D$ is integrally closed.

Please give me some hints! I'm really stuck on this problem and lost on the right directions! Thanks very much!

Comment: What is $F_3$ -- the field with three elements? Did you want to type it as $\mathbb{F}_3$? If so, you can use `\mathbb{F}_3` in your formulas (assuming the formula as a whole is enclosed in dollar signs).

Comment: @zipirovich Thx! That's exactly what I want! I'm also a beginner in Latex...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a quite verbose expansion of @LordSharktheUnknown's answer. Though this appears not suited for a beginner in commutative algebra.

$\def\f{\Bbb F}\def\z{\mathbf{Z}}$
We want to find all prime ideals of ${\Bbb F}_3[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x)$ whose
intersection with $\f_3[x]$ is $(x^2+x+2)$.

The *elliptic curve* $y^2=x^3-x$ means the scheme
$\text{Spec}(\f_3[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x))$. Denote it as $E$. Then
the prime ideals in the quotient ring are nothing but points of $E$
over $\f_3$. Denote the residue field of $p$ as $\kappa_p$, i.e.
$$\kappa_p=\f_3[x,y]/p.$$

Now consider the maps:
$$\f_3[x]\rightarrow\f_3[x,y]\rightarrow\f_3[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x).$$

And for every point $p$ on $E$ over $\f_3$, consider the composite map:
$$\f_3[x]\rightarrow\f_3[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x)\rightarrow\f_3[x,y]/p=\kappa_p.$$
If the intersection of $p$ with $\f_3[x]$ is $(x^2+x+2)$, then this
map has kernel $(x^2+x+2)$, and hence induces the map
$$\f_3[x]/(x^2+x+2)\hookrightarrow\kappa_p.$$

But this ring $\f_3[x]/(x^2+x+2)$ is isomorphic to $\f_9$, as the polynomial
$x^2+x+2$ is irreducible over $\f_3$, thus the residue field $\kappa_p$ is an
extension of $\f_9$. That is to say, $p$ is a point of $E$ defined over $\f_9$
if and only if the intersection of $p$ with $\f_3[x]$ is $(x^2+x+2)$.

---

It is a standard fact that the ring $\f_3[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x)$ is a Dedekind domain, so every
ideal can be uniquely factored into products of prime ideals. Therefore we are
looking for the prime ideal factorisation of the ideal $(x^2+x+2)$.

By the fact that [every ideal in a Dedekind domain is generated by at most two
elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597543/in-a-dedekind-domain-every-ideal-is-either-principal-or-generated-by-two-element), we can write $p$ as $(x^2+x+2,f(x,y))$ for some polynomial $f$.

Now $p$ contains $(y^2-x^3+x)$ means that $y-x^3+x$ can be written as a linear
combination of $x^2+x+2$ and $f$: $y-x^3+x=\alpha(x^2+x+2)+\beta f$ for some
$\alpha$ and $\beta$.

A calculation shows that $x^3-x=(x+1)^2\pmod{x^2+x+2}$. So we find that $f=y-x-1$ and $f=y+x+1$ satisfy the condition, and they give all the prime ideals we want to find.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer! It greatly helps for me!

Answer (score 3):

In effect you are looking for points on the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-x$
over the field $\Bbb F_9$. Let $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ be the solutions
of $x^2+x+2=0$ in $\Bbb F_9$. Consider $\beta_i=\alpha_i^3-\alpha_i$.

Two possibilities: (i) the $\beta_i$ are squares in $\Bbb F_9$,
(ii) the $\beta_i$ are non-squares in $\Bbb F_9$.

In (i) then $\beta_i=f(\beta_i)^2$ in $\Bbb F_9$ for some polynomial
$f$ with integer coefficients, and the ideals you seek are
$(x^2+x+2,y\pm f(x))$.

In (ii) then $(x^2+x+2)$ is already prime.

I'll leave you to do the required finite field calculation.

Comment: Umm...I wonder that why the F3 becomes to F9 here...

Comment: Would you (or someone else) mind expanding on this answer? I feel like it is not detailed enough for OP to understand.